Django request is slow but sql seem to be fast, need advice on how to debug
Django admin pages take very long time to load, debugged using django-debug-toolbar.
It shows the request is taking very long time

However, the sql queries seem to fast

What exactly does this mean? Is the time spent on processing and returning the request but not on the sql execution? Appreciate any advice on how to debug this further.
